# MOSFET/IGBT identification

Tags: mosfet, identification, igbt

I was repairing the PCB of my Refrigerator and found that IGBT/MOSFET was not giving output. I tried to search it but couldn't found the part. Please Help me in finding this part online.

[image]

Comment: is anything printed in the component? .... please add that info to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STGD5H60DF on digikey.com
direct link:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/STGD5H60DF/6003551?s=N4IgjCBcoLQdIDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRABYBOAdhAF0BfBggJlJAGUAVAAgEsA5gCMALiALcA4gBEArAAl6DIA

Comment: It is out of stock everywhere in the world :(

Comment: Why do you think this is the same FET?

Comment: It looks to be the same, based on marking